# Javascript convert array of array of string to array of array of number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am new in Javascript and I looking for the neatest way to convert

```
x=[[["0","0"],["1","1"],["2","1.5"]],[["0","0.1"],["1","1.1"],["2","2"]]]
```

into

```
[[[0,0],[1,1],[2,1.5]],[[0,0.1],[1,1.1],[2,2]]]
```

Except for using two `for` loops to implement this method, is there any shortcut alternative  in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
x = [
  [
    ["0", "0"],
    ["1", "1"],
    ["2", "1.5"]
  ],
  [
    ["0", "0.1"],
    ["1", "1.1"],
    ["2", "2"]
  ]
];

var res = x.map(function(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(arr1) {
    return arr1.map(Number);
  });
})

console.log(res);
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
x = [
  [
    ["0", "0"],
    ["1", "1"],
    ["2", "1.5"]
  ],
  [
    ["0", "0.1"],
    ["1", "1.1"],
    ["2", "2"]
  ]
];

var res = x.map(arr => arr.map(arr1 => arr1.map(Number)));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Swooping in with the obnoxious one-liner edition!

`const result = x.map(y => y.map(z => z.map(Number)))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursive approach for nested arrays.

```js
var x = [[["0", "0"], ["1", "1"], ["2", "1.5"]], [["0", "0.1"], ["1", "1.1"], ["2", "2"]]],
    result = x.map(function iter(a) {
        return Array.isArray(a) ? a.map(iter) : +a;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```